# Opening base64 image from html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot, html2canvas

I'm trying to actually view the string image that html2canvas is rendering.  I have a web page that opens from a hyperlink.  I want in the end to use the Image button to take a screen shot of the web page.  I am getting the base64 string but how do I view the string image?

```
      $(document).ready(function(){         

      html2canvas(document.body,{
          onrendered: function (canvas){
              var data = canvas.toDataURL();
              alert(data);
          },
          width:300,
          height:300
      });
```

Comment: How do you want to view it? In a new tab? Do you want to download it? What is the end result in viewing it you hope to achieve?

Comment: I'd like for it to be a download

Answer (score 6):

You do that by appending something like `data:image/png;base64,` to the base64 string, and using it as the source for an image tag that is inserted somewhere :

```
  html2canvas(document.body,{
      onrendered: function (canvas){
          var data = canvas.toDataURL();
          var img  = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('download','myImage.png');
          img.src  = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      },
      width:300,
      height:300
  });
```

Comment: I still didnt get that to work.  I put an alert box in to see what was rendering and it was just the base64 string still.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Answer from @adeneo, instead of:

```
img.src  = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
```

try this:

```
img.src  = data;
```

since the data image prefix is already inside the data variable.